# How to use runAction syntax correctly for the following

Tags: ios, swift, skaction

I'm trying to do the following

```
//increase spaceship frequency
    self.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.waitForDuration(1), completion: {

        difficulty -= 0.01
        println("difficulty increased")

    }))
```

Basically I need the SKAction.waitForDuration(1) with the completion to run forever so I tried to wrap it around with another runAction

I get the following error:
"Extra argument 'completion' in call"

Comment: Because the completion block is being treated as a parameter to repeatActionForever, which does not accept a completion parameter.

Comment: If you tell an action to repeat forever, it'll never complete!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to use `SpriteKit`, use a action sequence:

```
self.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration(1), SKAction.runBlock({
    difficulty -= 0.01;
    println("difficulty increased");
})])));
```

But, you really should be using [`NSTimer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/index.html).

Comment: I'm surprised that sequence is the only way to achieve this. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @AceGreen As I stated in my answer, you should look into using NSTimer

Comment: Yea but I'm using sprite kit so I wanted to use an action. Anyways I got it working by not waiting 1s but instead everytime I hit a spaceship I run the completion action.